# Menuitem action openERP 7

Tags: python, module, odoo, openerp-7

I'd like to know if is possible to make a "button" in the products menu that opens a dialog with the buttons "Continue" or "Cancel" and than, on clicking "Continue", I would like to call "my_function" that calculate the ean13 code of ***all*** the products

Here is an image that explain what i want to do with the update modules list example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMCaV.png

Comment: Please explain your question more elaborately.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, substantially it's the same thing than the "Update Modules List" menuitem in Settings, exactly the same thing.
It opens a new window that tells you if you want to continue with the update or cancel the request, the only difference is that my menuitem have to update the ean13 field in the product.product for all the products.

Comment: First of all that's not a new window that's Boostrap Modal you can find it here : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

and the next thing you have to put your code where you want to have modal in your code. You can directly call modal.

Comment: Wait, i didn't understand, where and which code i have to put in the xml file? Or better, how can i put that javascript code in the xml file? Sorry, maybe those are stupid questions for you, but i'm new to openerp

Comment: Okay, I am telling that you have to modal on your button click event in js but you have to define your html view for your dialog box as an template in xml. Now on Button click event you have to call that design template from xml to js. 

If you are new to OpenERP better you please read https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/training/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that's not a new window that's Bootstrap Modal you can find it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).
On your button click event in js but you have to define your html view for your dialog box as an template in xml.
Now on Button click event you have to call that design template from xml to js.

If you are new to OpenERP better you please [read](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/training)